Comparing .loc/.iloc to tuples and chained indexing
import pandas as pd

# Creating a DataFrame with some sample data
data = {
    'Name': [Jason, 'Emma', 'Alex', 'Sarah'],
    'Age': [28, 24, 32, 27],
    'City': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris', 'Tokyo'],
    'Salary': [75000, 65000, 85000, 70000]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

I want to update Jason’s age, and I do so with 

df['Age'][df['Name'] == 'Jason'] = 29

For code such as the code shown above, the df may or may not be update Jason's age to 29 due to the chained indexing that is being used.
The documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy mentions how .iloc/.loc is a better option. For example, something such as the following.
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Jason', 'Age'] = 29

However it is not clear about best practices regarding tuples, such as the following.
df[('Age', df['Name'] == 'Jason')] = 29 

I am trying to understand how the use of tuples would compare to the use of .iloc/.loc and the use of chained indexing in the context of best practices in pandas. Considerations can include time complexity, space complexity, code readability, etc.

You want to use dataframe.at to assign a single value

df[('Age', df['Name'] == 'Jason')] = 29 is not valid code and will give an Error. BTW Jason should be 'Jason' in data.

The best approach is to use an index. It seems that the attribute "Name" is being used as the index here.
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
df.loc['Jason', 'Age'] = 29

I would recommend adding another attribute, such as "ID," as the index instead.

Using Name as an index assumes Names are unique, no? And setting an index modifies the DataFrame structure just to do a simple value update.
Finally, if you need to filter/update based on different columns frequently, you'd have to keep changing the index.
Do you believe that what you suggested is better than the tuple or iloc/loc approaches?
